# Add border property to a span element

Tags: html, css, angular-ui

I have a `span` element (a star rating created by a [Angular-UI Rating](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/rating) (link to Plunkr at the bottom). I want to apply a border to the entire span (rating) element so that I can alert the user when there is a form submit without rating. (similar to `has-error` class for form validation). I'm planning to do this by applying a red border to the span element.

How can I accomplish this?

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/m0H2DZwwwtS2deMB75ON?p=preview

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('RatingDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.rate = 7;
  $scope.max = 10;
  $scope.isReadonly = false;

  $scope.hoveringOver = function(value) {
    $scope.overStar = value;
    $scope.percent = 100 * (value / $scope.max);
  };

  $scope.ratingStates = [
    {stateOn: 'glyphicon-ok-sign', stateOff: 'glyphicon-ok-circle'},
    {stateOn: 'glyphicon-star', stateOff: 'glyphicon-star-empty'},
    {stateOn: 'glyphicon-heart', stateOff: 'glyphicon-ban-circle'},
    {stateOn: 'glyphicon-heart'},
    {stateOff: 'glyphicon-off'}
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.3.0.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <div ng-controller="RatingDemoCtrl">
    <h4>Default</h4>
    <span uib-rating ng-model="rate" max="max" read-only="isReadonly" on-hover="hoveringOver(value)" on-leave="overStar = null" titles="['one','two','three']" aria-labelledby="default-rating"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please show your code?

Comment: added a plunker for the rating element I want a boarder over

Comment: Make the span inline-block and add border

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the span as inline-block element and apply border to it

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('RatingDemoCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.rate = 7;
  $scope.max = 10;
  $scope.isReadonly = false;

  $scope.hoveringOver = function(value) {
    $scope.overStar = value;
    $scope.percent = 100 * (value / $scope.max);
  };

  $scope.ratingStates = [{
    stateOn: 'glyphicon-ok-sign',
    stateOff: 'glyphicon-ok-circle'
  }, {
    stateOn: 'glyphicon-star',
    stateOff: 'glyphicon-star-empty'
  }, {
    stateOn: 'glyphicon-heart',
    stateOff: 'glyphicon-ban-circle'
  }, {
    stateOn: 'glyphicon-heart'
  }, {
    stateOff: 'glyphicon-off'
  }];
});
```

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.3.0.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <div ng-controller="RatingDemoCtrl">
    <h4>Default</h4>
    <span uib-rating ng-model="rate" max="max" read-only="isReadonly" on-hover="hoveringOver(value)" on-leave="overStar = null" titles="['one','two','three']" aria-labelledby="default-rating"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

to add a border to a span you can do following

```
span {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Penkey Suresh Add following CSS. You can adjust border color and padding according to your requirement.

```css
.ng-scope h4 + span{
border: 1px solid #ccc;
padding:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

style your border  by apply some css properties like this

> span {   border :2px dotted red;/* border-width border-style
>   border-color*/   }

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('RatingDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.rate = 7;
  $scope.max = 10;
  $scope.isReadonly = false;

  $scope.hoveringOver = function(value) {
    $scope.overStar = value;
    $scope.percent = 100 * (value / $scope.max);
  };

  $scope.ratingStates = [
    {stateOn: 'glyphicon-ok-sign', stateOff: 'glyphicon-ok-circle'},
    {stateOn: 'glyphicon-star', stateOff: 'glyphicon-star-empty'},
    {stateOn: 'glyphicon-heart', stateOff: 'glyphicon-ban-circle'},
    {stateOn: 'glyphicon-heart'},
    {stateOff: 'glyphicon-off'}
  ];
});
```

```css
span {
  border :2px dotted red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.3.0.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <div ng-controller="RatingDemoCtrl">
    <h4>Default</h4>
    <span uib-rating ng-model="rate" max="max" read-only="isReadonly" on-hover="hoveringOver(value)" on-leave="overStar = null" titles="['one','two','three']" aria-labelledby="default-rating"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**css:**

```
.redborder
{
color:red;
}
```

**html code:**

```
<p>this is sample text <span class="redborder">This is span text</span></p>
```